# Add Device with Removable Storgae\Map Network Drive to Windows

Tags: c#, network-drive

my client asked me to replicate the services provided by this [SpeedyDrive](http://www.speedydrive.net/%20Speedy%20Drive) software.

**SpeedyDrive** is a tool which basically uploads your selected files to a remote server which you can access from anywhere with legitimate account credentials.

1. On the non basic side, to enhance *usability*, it **"SAYS"** that it
   has mapped a network drive which you can access when you log-in. You
   can see it's icon in the screen shot below which appears when you 
   log-in and disappears when you log-out.

   [image: Speedy Drive]
2. Further more, you don't select files to be uploaded(SAVED ONLINE),
   you copy-paste them in this drive and it does this uploading
   abstractly.
3. Further more more, it even shows 4TB of space and and its file system named DOKAN.

**My Question is how to do 1,2,3 with C#, if not then HOW WITH C++ ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated by Hans and Erik, there is no reliable way to implement this type of functionality in pure C#.  It requires a windows driver, and drivers cannot be created with C#.  However, there are 3rd party drivers you can use.  Here are a two products that have C# libraries that enable code interaction with an underlying file system driver:

http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/  <-- Callback File System "Create and manage virtual filesystems and disks from your Windows applications"

http://dokan-dev.net/en/  <-- the Dokan "user mode file system for windows"  ... looks like SpeedyDrive uses this

Comment: Dokan is exactly what Speedy Drive are using

Comment: another question, technically what would my problem is known as "creating virtual drives & shell extensions"

Comment: You could probably do what you want with a "shell namespace extension".  I know you could use either of the libraries I've mentioned above, which will install a "file system driver".  What you are trying to do could be technically "known as" either of those two: namespace extension or file system driver.

Comment: the accurate answer is 1st. install Dokan 2nd. install .NET binding 3rd. Install Dokan SSHFS.

Comment: The accurate answer to what question?

Comment: a small extension to your answer... it is actually Dokan SSHFS  library which provides the methods to define a File System over a  remote storage

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with pure C#.  In order to do this you have to create a hardware driver that emulates a drive (which to my knowledge cannot be done in the CLR), but in actuality does what you want (like displaying whatever amount of space you want).  This is by no means a small project.